# Int array pushed through while loop until it reaches -1

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have to take a single line of user input, and calculate the average of all the numbers until it reaches -1 using a while loop. An example of user input could be something like 2 -1 6 which is why I've done it this way. I've figured out how to split this into an int array, but I can't figure out how to do the while loop portion.

```java
System.out.println("user input")
String user = scan.nextLine();
String[] string = user.split(" ");
int[] numbers = new int[string.length];
for(int i = 0;i < string.length;i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(string[i]);
}
while ( > -1){
            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) has methods `hasNextInt` and `nextInt`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter series of integers on single line separated by spaces.");
        System.out.println("For example: 2 -1 6");
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            if (num == -1) {
                break;
            }
            sum += num;
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            double average = sum / (double) count;
            System.out.println("Average: " + average);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to cast `count` to a double when calculating the average otherwise integer division will be performed and that will not give the correct average.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("user input");
        String user = scan.nextLine();
        boolean found = false;
        Double average = 0.0;
        
        
        String[] string = user.split(" ");
        int[] numbers = new int[string.length];
        for(int i = 0;i < string.length && found == false ;i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(string[i]);
        }
        int t = 0;
        while (found == false && t < string.length){
              if(numbers[t] == - 1){
                average = average/t;
                found = true;
              }
              else{
                    average = (Double) average + numbers[t];
                    t++;
                  }            
        }
        System.out.println("Average = " + average);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post all the code ? I mean, also the declaration of scan please ?

Comment: Not at all, I am really sorry if I let intend you this. I didn't have a compiler yesterday, so I could not check my errors. I modify my code and it seems working fine

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean, when user input number is -1. we should take average of all number before -1. that is was I am doing here.

```
System.out.println("user input")
String user = scan.nextLine();
int totalSum = 0;
double avg = 0;

String[] string = user.split(" ");
int[] numbers = new int[string.length];
for(int i = 0;i < string.length;i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(string[i]);
    if(numbers[i]==-1){
        avg = (double)totalSum / i;
        break;
    }
    totalSum += numbers[i]; 
}
```

**With only while loop**

```
System.out.println("user input");
String user = scan.nextLine();
int totalSum = 0;
double avg = 0;

String[] string = user.split(" ");
int[] numbers = new int[string.length];
int i = 0;
numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(string[i]);
while(numbers[i]!=-1) {
    totalSum += numbers[i];
    i++;
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(string[i]); 
}
avg = (double)totalSum / i;
```